# App Engine: Can I set a req/min rate instead of req/sec in queue.yaml?

Tags: google-app-engine, message-queue

Google has a 15000/min limit on the number of reads and writes. To stay under this limit, I calculated 15000/min == 250/sec, so my queue config is:

```
name: mapreduce-queue
rate: 200/s
max_concurrent_requests: 200
```

Can I directly set a rate of 15000/min in queue.yaml? I used 200/s because 15000/min == 250/sec adjusted for bursts. Also, I feel like I should not need the max_concurrent_requests limit at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.
However, use `15000/m` instead of `15000/min`

From [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue)

> rate (push queues only)
>
> How often tasks are processed on this queue. The value is a number
>   followed by a slash and a unit of time, where the unit is s for
>   seconds, **m for minutes**, h for hours, or d for days. For example, the
>   value 5/m says tasks will be processed at a rate of 5 times per
>   minute.
>
> If the number is 0 (such as 0/s), the queue is considered "paused,"
>   and no tasks are processed.

and

> max_concurrent_requests (push queues only)
>
> Sets the maximum number of tasks that can be executed at any given
>   time in the specified queue. The value is an integer. By default, this
>   directive is unset and there is no limit on the maximum number of
>   concurrent tasks. **One use of this directive is to prevent too many
>   tasks from running at once or to prevent datastore contention.**
>
> Restricting the maximum number of concurrent tasks gives you more
>   control over your queue's rate of execution. For example, you can
>   constrain the number of instances that are running the queue's tasks.
>   Limiting the number of concurrent requests in a given queue allows you
>   to make resources available for other queues or online processing.

It seems to me that for your situation, `max_concurrent_requests` is something you don't want to leave out